# Pythonのpandasの置換を行おうとしたところ、括弧で囲まれた文字の置換が上手く出来ない

Tags: python, pandas

Python pandasで日付が入った列の書式がバラバラのため、置換して整えようと考えています。
ここに記載するデータ以外にも多数のデータがあり、ほとんどの書式は「%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S」 となっている為、それに合わせるべく要らない部分を消そうと考えています。

```
import pandas as pd

tmp  = pd.DataFrame({"date": ["2018-03-31 09:15:53", 
                              "2018年04月01日(日) 07時00分57秒", 
                              "2018年04月07日"]}
                    )

tmp.date = tmp.date.str.replace("(日)", "")

print(tmp)

#                     date
#0     2018-03-31 09:15:53
#1  2018年04月01() 07時00分57秒
#2              2018年04月07
```

しかし、 「(日)」を置換したら、括弧内の漢字のみ置換され括弧が残ってしまい
その上、2018年04月07日 の日 まで置換され 2018年04月07 となっしまいます。

部分に完全一致するもののみを完全に置換するにはどのようにすればよいのでしょうか。

> バージョン
>   Python 3.6.3
>   pandas (0.22.0)

Comment: pandasの[str.replaceの第1引数は正規表現パターン](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.replace.html)のようなので、`(`, `)`は正規表現のメタ文字として扱われているようです。`"(日)"`を`r"\(日\)"`としてみるとどうなりますか?

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。`"\(日\)"` または `u"\(日\)"` でうまくいきました。ちなみに `r"\(日\)"` でやってみると、`"(日)"` とした場合と同じ結果になりました。不思議でしたが解決することが出来ました。ありがとうございます！

Comment: python2と違い、python3ではただの文字列と Unicode 文字列の違いはないので、`u"文字列"` のように `u` をつける必要はありません。また `r` をつけた文字列ではエスケープシーケンスが無視されるため、`r"\("` は `"\\("` と解釈されてしまいます。ご参考までに。

Comment: 要らないんですね。はっきりと理解できていなかった部分がスッキリしました。`r`についても理解できました。ありがとうございます！

Answer (score 1, accepted):

頂いたコメントで解決できました。回答しないとクローズ出来ないようですので
コメントを元に解決したコードを記載して解決とします。

```
import pandas as pd

tmp  = pd.DataFrame({"date": ["2018-03-31 09:15:53", 
                          "2018年04月01日(日) 07時00分57秒", 
                          "2018年04月07日"]}
                )

tmp.date = tmp.date.str.replace("\(日\)", "")
```